# How to implement fuzzy search for Chinese pinyin and Japanese romaji?

Tags: fuzzy-search, cjk

I have some data in Chinese and Japanese, and I want it possible to search by their romanizations (Pinyin for Chinese, Romaji for Japanese). Assume that the romanizations are already provided, separated by syllables.

eg. the text `"示例文本"`, which romanizes to `["shi", "li", "wen", "ben"]`.

Users should be able to match this by typing

- whole syllables, with or without space, eg. `shi li wen ben` or `shiliwenben`
- initials or first few letters of syllables, eg. `shlwb` or `slwb`
- they might also type only part of the string, eg. `wenben` or `wb` (these examples correspond to the last two syllables of the text above).

Is there an elegant way of implementing this?

(note: I did not specify any programming language in this question, because I want to implement this in different languages. If your response is language-specific or requires specific libraries, please make it clear. Thank you!)

Comment: While it seems possible to search for whole syllables, and part of the string I don't see how you can implement partial strings. For example, what is making shlwb refer uniquely to shi li wen ben instead of, for example, shi hao li wen ben (btw I don't know if this is a correct sentence in Chinese)

Comment: Re Hirabayashi Taro: both should return as results.